# What do they really mean by class incremental learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I war reading [Class-incremental learning: survey and performance
evaluation on image classification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.15277.pdf). I do not understand clearly what system do we expect at the end. It is **1.** or **2.**

**1.**

> train a model to predict whether inputs belongs to the class A or B:
> model 1
>
> train model 1 to predict whether inputs belongs to the class C or D:
> model 2

or

**2.**

> train a model to predict whether inputs belongs to the class A or B:
> model 1
>
> train model 1 to predict whether inputs belongs to the class A, B, C or D:
> model 2

which one is considered when people refers to the *class incremental learning*.

Please warn me if "data science" is better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your two options, option 2 is certainly closer to the correct answer, because your first option appears equivalent to training two independent models. Note that in general incremental learning is not limited to the case of adding new classes to the training data though.

Incremental learning means that the training can be extended:

- In a traditional setting, the model is trained on a fixed training set all at once. If one wants to change anything about the model, for instances add some training instances, then the only option is to fully retrain the model with the new training set made of both the old and new instances.
- With incremental learning, a model previously trained on some dataset $X_1$ can be "updated" by training it *more* on dataset $X_2$ (which doesn't include $X_1$). In theory the model should be able to classify any new instance, whether it's similar to $X_1$ or $X_2$. This includes the case where a new class which wasn't in $X_1$ is added in $X_2$.